# Filename has weird encoding when saving image

Tags: python, string, encoding

I'm webscraping, and when I'm saving the image, it seems like the encoding is changed when saving the file. For instance, in the filename, `'é'` becomes `'%c3%a9'`. I'm capable of catching all these changes with this function:

```
def unify_filename(string):  
    return string.lower().strip().replace(',', '%2c').replace('%', '%25').replace('ô', '%b3%b4'). \
        replace('é', '%c3%a9').replace('++', '+').replace('è', '%c3%a8').replace('î', '%c3%ae'). \
        replace('#', '%23').replace(';', '%3b').replace('%2b%2b', '%2b'). \
        replace('&', '%26').replace('+', '%2b').replace(' ', '+').replace('[', '%5b'). \
        replace(']', '%5d').replace('%2b', '+').replace('%40', '@').replace('®', '%c2%ae'). \
        replace('%7e', '').replace('~', '').replace('%27', '').replace('©', '%c2%a9'). \
        replace("'", '').replace('ô', '%b3%b4').replace('+', ' ').replace('^', '%5e'). \
        replace('$', '%24').replace('  ', ' ').replace('`', '%60').replace('’', '%e2%80%99')
```

Is there an easier way? Is this some encoding I don't know?

Comment: I believe that's just the [utf-8 hex](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm) representation of é.

Comment: It does look like that. Mine has a `%` in between though. Do you know of a way to convert those programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle these values using [`urllib` parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html). you can use the [`unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) function.

Use the following piece of code:

```
import urllib.parse
print(urllib.parse.unquote('%c3%a9', encoding='utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
'é'
```

Comment: In my case I had to use `urllib.parse.quote_plus` to because `' '` was also replaced by `'+'`